# Open a large html file on browser

Tags: java, browser, swt

I have a desktop bassed eclipse plugin application. In which, for a case I am opening html report file in browser.

for which I am using this:

```
try {
    browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
    browser
    .setUrl(path);
    shell.open();
}
catch (SWTError e) {
    e.printStacktrace();
}
```

But in one case I am having html file of 90 MB which is not able to get open by it. It got hanged.
So request you for any action around it need to be done.
On any other optimized way to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the whole file, load it on demand.

[Window onscroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll) is your friend.

Comment: @Suresh atta Logic is appreciable i initially thought it but not idea about implementation. Pls remeber I am working on SWt so how it could be implemented here.

Comment: @RTA That java script should be inside that html page.

Comment: @Suresh atta I can not use java script in swt code.

Comment: You can use that in html page right ????? There is nothing to do with SWT. Place your script inside the html.

Comment: @Suresh ATTA But i have doubt that on desktop application when we give url as above code browser will take whole code at one time, then will it be able to show content on chunks at scroll event. pls elaborate.